# PHP complex replacing of bracketed variables in text

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have an email template I've created and I want to be able to use things like [NAME], [EMAIL], [PHONE] and replace them when it's sent. Those are easy, but I also have other more complex tags like [PRODUCT:12], [ARTICLE:23] etc. where I want to read in the first part as the 'type' and then handle the second part as the value.

I'm guessing I'll need some sort of preg_match and then preg_replace, but I'm really at a loss here as I'm not good at those functions.

Any suggestions?

---EDIT---

Just to be clear. The problem lies in the two part bracketed var:value pairs. I need to be able to see that it's PRODUCT and do a look up of id=12 returning the product so I can make a link.

---EDIT 2---

```
public function parse_message_tags($matches){

    $keys = explode(':', $matches[1]);
    $key = $keys[0];
    $id = (array_key_exists(1, $keys)) ? $keys[1] : -1;
    switch ($key) {
       case 'NAME':
          return $this->session->member->name();
       break;
       case 'FIRST_NAME':
          return $this->session->member->first_name;
       break;
       case 'EMAIL':
          return $this->session->member->email;
       break;
       case 'PRODUCT':
          $product = Product::find_by_id($id);
          return '<a href="/products/'.$product->seo_name.'">'.$product->name.'</a>';
       break;
       case 'ARTICLE':
          $product = Article::find_by_id($id);
          return '<a href="/blog/'.$article->seo_title.'">'.$article->name.'</a>';
       break;
    }

}

public function parse_message($input)
{
    $pattern = '/\[(NAME|FIRST_NAME|EMAIL|PHONE|PRODUCT:\d+|ARTICLE:\d+)\]/';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, create_function('$matches', 'return self::parse_message_tags;'), $input);

}
```

Result:

Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active

OR

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

I'm guessing the create_function() takes you out of scope/context. And obviously I'm using class methods here so simply calling 'parse_message_tags' is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done relatively clean using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$pattern = '/\[(NAME|EMAIL|PHONE|PRODUCT:\d+|ARTICLE:\d+)\]/';

function callbackHandler($matches) {
    $keys = explode(':', $matches[1]);
    $key = $keys[0];
    $id = (array_key_exists(1, $keys)) ? $keys[1] : -1;
    switch ($key) {
        case 'NAME':
            return '##name##';
        break;
        case 'EMAIL':
            return '##email##';
        break;
        case 'PHONE':
            return '##phone##';
        break;
        case 'PRODUCT':
            return '##product id:'.$id.'##';
        break;
        case 'ARTICLE':
            return '##article id:'.$id.'##';
        break;
    }
}

$string = "Hello [NAME], have you checked out our latest product [PRODUCT:32]. We're sure you'll like it! If you don't we'll call you on [PHONE] and link you to [ARTICLE:12], which will put your email ([EMAIL]) on our hourly email newsletter";

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callbackHandler', $string);
```

Returns:

> Hello ##name##, have you checked out our latest product ##product id:32##. We're sure you'll like it! If you don't we'll call you on ##phone## and link you to ##article id:12##, which will put your email (##email##) on our hourly email newsletter

## [See it on codepad](http://codepad.org/I0gn1IR1)

Comment: This is the best answer, but there's no need for all of the extra functions. Handle it all within the cases.

Comment: I'm running in to an issue though because I need to keep this in object context and preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callbackHandler', $string); doesn't accomplish that. I would really need to call $this->callbackHandler, but that's not working. Any ideas there?

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as those extra functions are removed. As it stands people can't really see the whole answer and adding the functions is not really part of the answer.

Comment: Agreed, don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 2):

The function to use in this situation is preg_replace_callback(), since you need to perform a array look up on the index for the second type of tags. Wrapping the code in a class is useful here. We need to hand data to the callback function somehow. Using global variables would be ugly.

```
class EmailTemplate {

    protected $text;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($text, $data) {
        $this->text = $text;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function callback($matches) {
        $replacement = null;
        $name = $matches[1];
        $index = (int) $matches[2];
        if(isset($this->data[$name])) {
            $value = $this->data[$name];
            if(is_scalar($value)) {
                $replacement = $value;
            } else {
                if(isset($value[$index])) {
                    $replacement = $value[$index];
                }
            }
        }
        return $replacement;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return preg_replace_callback('/\[(\w+)(?:\:(\d+))?\]/', array($this, 'callback'), $this->text);
    }
}

$data = array(
    "NAME" => "Bob",
    "PRODUCT" => array("dog", "cat", "eggplant")
);
$email = new EmailTemplate("Dear [NAME], please buy my [PRODUCT:2]", $data);

echo $email;
```

The pattern might look somewhat bewildering. The key here is the (?:  )? part. The second question mark indicates the pattern within, \:(\d+), is optional. The first question mark along with the colon groups the characters without capturing them. It's used here as we need just the number for the array look-up.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 for the array($this, 'callback') portion, that solved my issue with already being in a class and losing scope.

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches both with Id and should give you the Id in the text: `\[([A-Z]*):(\d*)\]`
The new regex `\[([A-Z]*:?\d*)\]` matches both.

Comment: Would this run into trouble for case #1 (`[ID]`)?

Comment: This doesn't match the first 3 Items (like [ID]) as they are handled differently.

Comment: Well I would need a single function as when the email body is parsed who knows whether it's [VAR] or [VAR:VAL]. The function has to determine and go from there.

Comment: Edited and added the functionality to match both.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function something like this:

```
function parse_tag($tag) {
  preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $tag, $matches);
  return explode(':', $matches[1]);
}
```

To put it into use, you might do something like the following:

```
$tests = array(
  '[NAME]' => array('NAME'),
  '[PRODUCT:SHIRT]' => array('PRODUCT', 'SHIRT'), 
  '[ARTICLE:23]' => array('ARTICLE', 23)
);

foreach($tests as $search => $expected) {
  $result = parse_tag($search);
  assert($expected == $result);
}
```

See a working example [here](http://ideone.com/wwzC2)